# Magento 2 : How to add product image from custom front-end form in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I have created a module to add product from front-end custom form. Currently the product is created in back-end but product image is not uploaded. If anyone having knowledge regarding this then please guide me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first remove all the product images and then you can set new images.

Please try below code

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
$productId =  1 ;
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);
$productRepository = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface');
$filesystem = $objectManager->create("\Magento\Framework\Filesystem");
$fileUploaderFactory = $objectManager->create("\Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory");

/* Remove exising product images first*/
$exisingEntries = $product->getMediaGalleryEntries();
foreach ($exisingEntries as $key => $entry) {
    unset($exisingEntries[$key]);
}
$product->setMediaGalleryEntries($exisingEntries);
$productRepository->save($product);

$mediapath = $filesystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath(); // 

$images = $this->getRequest()->getFiles('images');
if(count($files)){
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($images as $files) {
        if (isset($files['tmp_name']) && strlen($files['tmp_name']) > 0) {
            try {
                $uploader = $fileUploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => $images[$i]]);
                $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png']);
                $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
                $imagePath = $mediapath . 'productimages/';
                $data['images'] = $files['name'];
                $result = $uploader->save($imagePath);

                /* Set new product images */
                
                if($i == 0){
                    $product->addImageToMediaGallery($imagePath, array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'), false, false);    
                }
                else{
                    $product->addImageToMediaGallery($imagePath , null, true, false );    
                }
            }catch (\Exception $e) {
                // Exception
            }
        }
        $i++;
        $product->save();
    }
}
```

Make sure you have image on the path.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your answer @zealousWeb. I did the whole thing as you have mentioned but I need to select the image from my local system rather then provide the path of the image.
I am using this code to get the image data in controller  : $files = $this->getRequest()->getFiles();

Comment: In this case you need to first upload image on server. I have updated code, Please try it

Comment: Works Fine. Many Thanks! @zealousWeb